# Getting an error when summing price of room using a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to get the sum of all lost income for rooms not booked on certain day for each individual hotel.

- Hotel (hotelNo,hotelName,hotelAddress)
- Room (hotelNo,roomNo,type,price)
- Guest (guestNo,guestName,guestAddress)
- Booking (hotelNo,guestNo,dateFrom,dateTo,roomNo)

Here's the command I've got so far.  I feel like it's just a silly mistake and I'm missing something easy, but I just can't put my finger on it.

```
SELECT hotelNo, roomNo, (SUM)price AS "Lost Income"
FROM room r
WHERE roomNo NOT IN
(SELECT roomNo FROM booking b
WHERE to_date('20080706', 'yyyymmdd')
BETWEEN dateFrom AND dateTo
AND r.hotelno = b.hotelno)
ORDER BY hotelNo
GROUP BY hotelNo
```

Comment: Is that not the command to add up the price?

Comment: @Szymon "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"

Comment: Error `ORA`? Is that SQL Server or Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious thing is wrong parenthesis in `SUM`. Also, `ORDER BY` should be after `GROUP BY` and you need to convert date in a different way

```
SELECT hotelNo, SUM(price) AS "Lost Income"
FROM room r
WHERE roomNo NOT IN
(SELECT roomNo FROM booking b
WHERE to_date('20080706', 'yyyymmdd')
BETWEEN dateFrom AND dateTo
AND r.hotelno = b.hotelno)
GROUP BY hotelNo
ORDER BY hotelNo
```

Comment: When I run that, I get the error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Error: "ORA-00902: invalid datatype"

Comment: to_date is valid in oracle

Comment: OK, I thought it was SQL Server. That was the tag!

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong tag.   That code worked, but it does not sum up the price from all the rooms in every hotel.  It lists them individually

Comment: Ok, removed `roomNo` from grouping, that will sum up all the rooms.